# Making components not move when side menu opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, antd

I'm new at web development and struggling a little bit with my side-menu component from Ant design.

It's a collapsible menu that moves many others components when clicked to open it.

I want that all the others items on the page remain on the same position 
unattached of menu actions.

Thats the sidemenu component:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Layout, Menu, Breadcrumb, Icon, Button } from 'antd';

    const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;
    const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;

    export class SideMenu extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
            <Menu
              mode="vertical"
              theme="dark"
              className="side-menu"
            >
              ...
            </Menu>
        )
      }
    }

 Thats my layout component:

import React from 'react'
...
import { Layout, Menu, Icon, Row, Col } from 'antd'

const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout

export class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { collapsed: true }
  }

  toggle() {
    console.log('click')
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout className="main-layout">
        <Sider className='sider'
          trigger={null}
          collapsible
          collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
        >
          <div className="app-logo" id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Augecon_Logo" height="30" width="30"/>
          </div>
          <SideMenu />
        </Sider>
        <Layout>
          <Header className="app-header">
            <Row justify="center" align="middle">
              <Col span={3}>
                <Icon
                  className="app-trigger"
                  type={this.state.collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'}
                  onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col span={10} push={10}>
                <div className="app-info" >Sexta feira 12/01/2018 - 17:58 | Daniel Oliveira</div> <!--This item moves-->
              </Col>
              <Col span={3} push={8}>
                <UserAvatar/><!--This item moves-->
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Header>
            <Content className="app-background" >
              <div className="div-background">
                <div>
                  <img src="images/sagic.png" alt="sagic" className="img-title" center center fixed/> <!--This item moves-->
                </div>
                <Row type="flex" gutter={32} justify="space-around" className="row-card"> <!--This item moves-->
                  <Col span={7} push={1}>
                    <CardSuporte/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={7} push={1}>
                    <CardSugestoes/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={7} push={1}>
                    <CardLoja/>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
            </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

That's my layout component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { SideMenu } from './sidemenu.js'
import { UserAvatar} from './avatar.js'
import { CardSuporte} from './cardsuporte.js'
import { CardSugestoes} from './cardsugestoes.js'
import { CardLoja} from './cardloja.js'
import { Layout, Menu, Icon, Row, Col } from 'antd'

const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout

export class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { collapsed: true }
  }

  toggle() {
    console.log('click')
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout className="main-layout">
        <Sider className='sider'
          trigger={null}
          collapsible
          collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
        >
          <div className="app-logo" id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Augecon_Logo" height="30" width="30"/>
          </div>
          <SideMenu />
        </Sider>
        <Layout>
          <Header className="app-header">
            <Row justify="center" align="middle">
              <Col span={3}>
                <Icon
                  className="app-trigger"
                  type={this.state.collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'}
                  onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col span={10} push={10}>
                <div className="app-info" >Sexta feira 12/01/2018 - 17:58 | Daniel Oliveira</div>
              </Col>
              <Col span={3} push={8}>
                <UserAvatar/>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Header>
            <Content className="app-background" >
              <div className="div-background">
                <div>
                  <img src="images/sagic.png" alt="sagic" className="img-title" center center fixed/>
                </div>
                <Row type="flex" gutter={32} justify="space-around" className="row-card">
                  <Col span={7} push={1}>
                    <CardSuporte/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={7} push={1}>
                    <CardSugestoes/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={7} push={1}>
                    <CardLoja/>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
            </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

I already try some css manipulations like {position:fixed, relative, etc..} but without any result.

Answer (score 1):

I know I was a little late in answering...
I usually solve this problem as follows:

1. Make sidebar position fixed,but only for case it has className ".ant-sidebar-sider-below"

   .ant-layout-sider-below {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 999;
   height: 100%;
   }
2. Then you can fixed menu-trigger button, when sidebar has className ".ant-layout-sider-collapsed" with this css

   .ant-layout-sider-collapsed .ant-layout-sider-zero-width-trigger {
   position: fixed;
   left: 4px;
   right: auto;
   }

I created a small example [link](https://shorturl.at/lrxI1)
I hope this will be useful to someone

Comment: Link is dead.. :(

Comment: Found the link: https://codepen.io/IgorShcherba/pen/zYrewbP?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

When I do mobile menus, I wrap my whole menu in a div with id of nav, then I make sure that my whole nav div has position:absolute and z-index: 100000, which might not be necessary but just in case.  The position absolute takes it out of the rest of the page so it doesn't interact with other elements (and won't push them when the menu is open), and the z-index makes sure it always shows on top of other page elements.  Hopefully this helps!

Comment: How does this answers the question? Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer?

Comment: Hi @Jessica, 

I tryed like that:

#app-nav{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100000;
}

------

<div id="app-nav">
    <SideMenu />
</div>


But remains on the same way. Keep pushing other components.

Comment: @Yannis how does that answer the question?

Comment: @MichaelFernandes I'm glad you were able to find the answer, sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: @Jessica How does your proposed answer answers the question? (repeat x3) :/

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and discover that i did have to change the css properties of ant design to achieve the expected result. When i started doing this (position: absolute), other components attached to the side-menu (like button that make it collapse) are not show like before and become hidden between other stuff.

In resume i read that its not to much common change pre-buid componets like the ant desiner's components.

Our Product Owner decided to maintain the menu like it is.

Thanks for all help!